# Are web Applications with SSO a portal?

Tags: web-applications

I'm a bit baffled regarding the use of the "portal" keyword.

My understanding is that a portal is a general web page containing several portlets, each of which is a rendering of data fetched from a different source. Example: iGoogle

**Reason for my bafflement (it's a word, I [checked](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bafflement)):**

We built a set of web applications/services using IBM Websphere Portal for our client (a university). Each of the university services has its separate set of web pages (no portlets). The apps/services are accessed from the university's website using SSO (Single Sign-On). Our client uses the word "portal" to refer to them, although the concept of "portlets" doesn't exist.

So, is it a portal?

Comment: @John Conde Why did you close the question as off-topic? This is my first time using webmasters but I read the FAQ and felt it's related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "portal" means "doorway".  Any page which has a navigational purpose, rather than a content purpose is a portal page.  It doesn't have to be "portlets", just a page of links is often considered a portal page because it is nothing but a central doorway that allows quick access to a wide variety of resources.

Portal pages usually designed so that somebody could make them their default homepage.  At universities they usually have links news, weather, all university services, and feature important information such as links to class enrollment at the appropriate time.